# How to handle onClick event for each input type submit using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, firebug

I'm new to jQuery... Still learning it. But I need a quick solution to be able to register click event for each button in my table.

The following table is generated by GridView:

```
<div id="gridView">
                 <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-color:Red;border-collapse:collapse;position:absolute; top: 290px;" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults" rules="all">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th scope="col">ISONUM</th><th scope="col">OFFICE NAME</th><th scope="col">REGION</th><th scope="col">DIVISION</th><th scope="col">EMAIL ADDRESS</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoNum_0">222222222 </span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoOfficeName_0">My Test</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvRegion_0">99</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvDivision_0">11111</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <input type="text" style="width:200px;" onclick="ResetMessage();" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_0" value="mytest@google.com" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl02$txtgvEmailAddress">
                                <input type="submit" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_btnEmailUpdate_0" value="Update" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl02$btnEmailUpdate">
                            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoNum_1">CB2222001 </span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoOfficeName_1">DENNIS PETROVIC          </span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvRegion_1"></span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvDivision_1">99801</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <input type="text" style="width:200px;" onclick="ResetMessage();" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_1" value="dennis@dlgent.com" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl03$txtgvEmailAddress">
                                <input type="submit" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_btnEmailUpdate_1" value="Update" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl03$btnEmailUpdate">
                            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoNum_2">FT2222001 </span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoOfficeName_2">DENNIS PETROVIC          </span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvRegion_2"></span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvDivision_2">99801</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <input type="text" style="width:200px;" onclick="ResetMessage();" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_2" value="dennis@dlgent.com" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl04$txtgvEmailAddress">
                                <input type="submit" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_btnEmailUpdate_2" value="Update" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl04$btnEmailUpdate">
                            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

This table has a `Button` on each row, I just need to make sure that when button is clicked I will call my web service method to update a text field on the same row, but for that I need first to catch that event. I want to do it through jQuery/Ajax although I could have done it differently, this is preferred way in this case.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

---UPDATE---

I tried every suggestion given here, but for some reason, when clicking on the `button`, nothing happen. Is that possible that it may be related to my `grid` not generating any `html` for a table when viewing source for my page? The source I provided before, I got using `firebug`.

Comment: `$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) { /* do something */ });` - where "do something" could be a `$.ajax()` call, and within the function `$(this).closest('tr').find('something')` will let you get data from the same row as the clicked button.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).on("click", "#gridView input[type='submit']", function(){
   /* here is your clicked button's ID */
   console.log( "ID : "+ $(this).attr("id") );
   /* here is your clicked button's NAME */
   console.log( "NAME : "+ $(this).attr("name") );
   /* now call your web service using jquery Ajax */
   callService( $(this).attr("id"), $(this).attr("name") );
});


function callService( id, name ) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST', /* can be GET or POST */
      url: 'your web service url', /* your web service's url */
      data: { id : id, name : name }, /* post varibales */
      dataType : 'your data type', /* expected data types can be XML, JSON, HTML */
      success: function(data){ /* get called when response from your web service arrived */
         /* 'data' has the response data */             
         console.log(data); 
        /* you can get the text box of same row like */
         $( "#"+ id ).prev().val( /* set value for text box */ );
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: for some reason, when clicking on the button, nothing happen. I have my `.js` file referenced on my page. Is that possible that it may be related to my grid not generating any html for a table when viewing source for my page?

Comment: @eugene.it that case use jquery 'on' handler to bind click event. (i have updated my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [.on() method](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach an event handler to selected elements. In your case, it would look like this, although you may want to use a different selector. You could event just use $("input[type='submit']").on(...)

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#gridView div table tbody tr td input[type='submit']").on("click", handleClick); 
});

function handleClick() {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

Comment: Here's a link if you want to test it out - [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/n2MCu/)

Answer (score 0):

All answers are ok, but I guess you also need preventDefault

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#gridView input[type='submit']").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      /*do something, use $(this) to know wich button was pressed*/
 }); 
});
```

This is because you need to stop the propagation of your button.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why my `jQuery` did not fire the event. It was just because my GridView was inside of an `UpdatePanel` and that's why it was not loaded on a page at the time `click` event fired

Answer (score -1):

You can use delegate.

$("#gridView").delegate("input[type=submit]", "click", function() {

```
    alert("clicked!");

});
```

I used this for class delegation, not sure if would work for submit, but you could try.

Cheers

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method" - [link](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)